# Serilog - RollingFile Sink rolling fails based on the size

Tags: serilog

I am using Serilog.Sinks.File with version 3.2.0. and I would like to  roll-over logs based on the size. Currently, my 'fileSizeLimitBytes' is set 2000 bytes. When the log file size reaches the limit set in 'fileSizeLimitBytes', it does not roll-over fails and fails to log the messages. How can I roll-over the log file based on the size?

logging.json

```
"WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
              "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}][{ThreadId}]  {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}"
            }
        },
        {
          "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "path": "Logs\\Test.log",
            "formatter":"Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
            "rollingInterval": "Day",
            "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug",
            "retainedFileCountLimit": 5 ,
            "fileSizeLimitBytes": 2000
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you also need to specify `rollOnFileSizeLimit: true`.